# RegEx Matching a Pattern Only after The First Pattern Was Matched

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I am trying to return a match from a string only IFF the a another pattern is matched first in Oracle using `RegEx_Like` and `RegExp_Substr`, but I am getting mixed results.

Below is a sample of the data that I have and what I am trying to return from it:

```
+-----------------------------+---------+
|            Data             |  Goal   |
+-----------------------------+---------+
| 201301-P706466 JFK CLASSICS | P706466 |
| 201301-706466 WRI CLASSICS  | 706466  |
| 201301 706466 JFK CLASSICS  | 706466  |
| 201301 P706466 WRI CLASSICS | 706466  |
| 201910-MLB-CVG4             | NULL    |
| 201209-JFK CLASSICS         | NULL    |
| 201203-WRI CLASSICS         | NULL    |
| 201209 JFK CLASSICS         | NULL    |
| 201203 WRI CLASSICS         | NULL    |
+-----------------------------+---------+
```

**Query:**

```
select    pid.location
        , pnm.pn as mpn
        , pid.pn as pn
        , pid.batch
        , pid.goods_rcvd_batch as grb
        , pid.sn
        , pid.bin
        , Case When RegExp_Like(pid.bin, ''''^\d{6}\-|^\d{6}\s'''') Then RegExp_Substr(pid.bin, ''''\d{6}|(P)\d{6}.*?(\d{6})|((P)\d{6})'''') 
          End As Bin_Esn                        
from    pn_inventory_detail pid
join    pn_interchangeable pni on pid.pn = pni.pn_interchangeable
join    pn_master pnm on pni.pn = pnm.pn
where   pid.installed_ac is null
    and pid.owner is null
    and pid.loan_category is null
    and pid.nha_pn is null
```

I have tried different variations of [this](https://regex101.com/r/TiNJaC/1), but on regex101, but as you will see after navigating to the link, it is matching more than what I need.

I think I may be going about this the wrong way all together, which is why I am here. Saying that, what pattern works for my case, and is the most efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to reach your goal column mentioned in the question :

```
^\d{6}[-\s]{1}(\d{6}|P\d{6})
```

**Demo :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/TiNJaC/2)

Comment: That's close but no cigar. Modifying it to the following works though: `^\d{6}[-\s]{1}(\d{6}|(P)\d{6})`. See: https://regex101.com/r/68ypex/1

Comment: i could not tell by your data if there will be only the letter P at the begining or not as it's not mentioned so i tried to eliminate the three letters length instead.